# CakePHP v3: How to get patchEntity to update associations in request data

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using `patchEntity()` to update hasMany associations and it works fine. My problem is not related to the data that is saved in the DB. My problem is that the association data stored in the entity variable goes out of sync...

Notice in the method below that I have to do a second `get()` after the save to RE-read the data from the DB. If I remove this, the next view will show stale association data because patchEntity updates the foreign keys, but the actual association object is still the previous (from before the save).

I wish there was a way to not make two DB queries in a row. Is this the intended behavior? Is there a better way to do it?

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
    //1//////////////////////////////////////////
    $screen = $this->Screens->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Blocks'=>['Datasources'=>['Agencies']]] 
    ]);

    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {

        $screen = $this->Screens->patchEntity(  $screen, 
                                                $this->request->data, 
                                                [
                                                    'associated'=>['Blocks.Datasources']
                                                ]
                                            );
        if ($this->Screens->save($screen)) {

            //2//////////////////////////////////////////
            #get the UPDATED properties... specifically, the associations don't get updated automatically by patchEntity above
            $screen = $this->Screens->get($id, [
                'contain' => ['Blocks'=>['Datasources'=>['Agencies']]]
            ]);

            $this->Flash->success('The screen has been saved.');
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('The screen could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
    }

    $this->set(compact('screen'));
}
```

Comment: This isn't quite identical to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006015/reset-an-entity-or-create-a-new-empty-entity-in-controller-after-saving), but the answer is the same. You should be redirecting after the successful save, most usually to the view or index page.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I understand why that works but the solution is even more expensive than what I'm already doing. For anyone curious, the answer on that link is to just do a redirect after the save... Which will reset/redo everything

Comment: Besides that I don't get the picture based on your description (what exactly does the data, the patched, and the saved entity look like?), how is another DB read or even a redirect "expensive"? It's not like your action is being hammered with 1000 requests per second, or is it?

Comment: @ndm I just mean that my reason for asking the question in the first place was because it seemed wasteful to do `$this->Screens->get(...)` at the beginning of the save and then immediately again right after the save. It sounds like there is not a way to avoid it, but strictly from the perspective of resources, the way I'm currently doing it is more efficient than the solution Greg offered because it creates an entire new request, with ALL the db calls repeated. That was my only point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, of course, no way to avoid the second query. Even if the framework implemented the feature it would need to use another query to find the associations with the most recent data.

So while it seems wasteful, it is the only way to do it.

Comment: Thanks Jose. Any advice on whether to reset the variable with a second query (as I'm doing) or do a redirect? The solution in Greg's comment says you should ALWAYS redirect in situations like this...

Comment: There is an advantage in redirecting, which is that you will avoid annoying browser behavior if the user tries to click the back button. You will also save some code in your cotroller :P